# Writing a Matlab constraint unit test

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test that checks a constraint. I'm just trying to see how to use this:

```
classdef UnitTester < matlab.unittest.TestCase


    properties


    end

    methods (Test)

        function testCheckLessThan (testCase)
              testCase.verifyThat(2, IsLessThan(3));
        end

    end


end
```

When I run it using run(UnitTester) it comes up with the following error:

```
Uncaught error occurred in UnitTester/testCheckLessThan.

    --------------
    Error Details:
    --------------
    Undefined function 'IsLessThan' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to import the constraint in the function that uses it, like so:

```
classdef UnitTester < matlab.unittest.TestCase

    methods (Test)

        function testCheckLessThan (testCase)
              import matlab.unittest.constraints.IsLessThan;

              testCase.verifyThat(2, IsLessThan(3));
        end

    end   

end
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**
If you'd like to avoid importing the IsLessThan constraint in every method or local function in the file, you can effectively scope the namespace for IsLessThan by exploiting the fact that local functions can be used as a scoping mechanism. This looks like the following:

```
classdef UnitTester < matlab.unittest.TestCase

    methods (Test)

        function testCheckLessThan (testCase)    
              testCase.verifyThat(2, IsLessThan(3));
        end

        function testRange (testCase)    
              testCase.verifyThat(2, IsGreaterThan(1) & IsLessThan(3));
        end

    end   

end

% "import" functions
function c = IsGreaterThan(varargin)
c = matlab.unittest.constraints.IsGreaterThan(varargin{:});
end
function c = IsLessThan(varargin)
c = matlab.unittest.constraints.IsLessThan(varargin{:});
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there no way of doing it without importing a module in every time I need it?

Comment: Hey John, Yes and no. The scope of imports in MATLAB is currently limited to functions, meaning that each function needs to import what it needs. You can also add an import statement that uses ".*" to import the entire constraints package if you'd like, meaning if you wanted to use both IsLessThan and IsGreaterThan you'd only need one import statement. There is another way to do something that behaves very similar to a class level import, and I will update my answer to show that.